# Open CSV, Manipulate specific Entry, Save (should not be that hard..rirght?)

Tags: php, file, csv, edit

I need to open a CSV File with 60+ rows and three columns.
the third column in the file is a link. I need to add a String (ex.: "/ref="04" ") at the end of every Link and then safe it.

file looks like this

```
Products--------Description-------Link
Apple-----------blablabla---------http://www-anylink.com
Banana----------blablabla---------http://www-anylink.com
```

Should look like this afterwards (adding "/ref04" to the end of links)

```
Products--------Description-------Link
Apple-----------blablabla---------http://www-anylink.com/ref04
Banana----------blablabla---------http://www-anylink.com/ref04
```

SO the file i need to edit is for an affiliate program and i have never used PHP before. I figured out how to open and safe files, but i don't know how to edit it and put all together.
It should not be that hard but i can not find any example in the Internet.

Can anyone please help me i cant wrap my head around programing. I am trying but its hard.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you already tried, and explain what your specific problem with it was.

Comment: You’ll want to use fgetcsv and fputcsv for this. The rest is just working with/looping through arrays …

Comment: The [example for fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#example-2870) basically has what you need already: A while loop that goes over all the records in the inpuit CSV file one by one, and a for loop that goes over the individual cells of each record. If you just need to access one specific column, you probably don’t need a for loop in that place, but can access the column via index directly.

Comment: You could either use fputcsv directly inside the while loop, to write each record to a second file directly; or you put each line of $data into an array first, and then loop over that array again later to write each row to the target file. (Example for `fputcsv` shows a basic version of the latter.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, and to the world of programming. Although you'll find lots of helpful people here willing to help you fix problems or understand specific issues, this is not a code-writing service, or a good source for introductory tutorials. Depending on your preferred learning style, there are plenty of tutorials, videos, example programs, and mentoring programs out there which will help you get started. Then once you've got something working, or nearly working, you'll be able to ask (or search for) more specific questions, and get the best value out of this site.

Comment: Thank You for all your answers. Sorry for not providing any code. You helped me allready somehoooowww. Nex t time i wwill do it differently.